# Slow start of Midnight Commander

Tags: mc

Is there any way to prevent `mc` from taking 10-30 seconds to open?

Comment: Did you compile it with `--enable-vfs-smb`? Try disabling the feature. Seems to be a common problem with version 4.8.4: [mc starting up very SLOW](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/mc-devel/2012-December/msg00000.html)

Comment: Run `strace -r -tt -o mc.strace mc` to see where it's taking time. Upload the trace file if you need help interpreting it. Note that the trace file may contain private information (at least file names), take a look at it and sanitize it if necessary before uploading.

Comment: had the same problem, added hostname to /etc/hosts (as 127.0.0.1, of course), all became perfect

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works for me now. I am using

> GNU Midnight Commander 4.8.21

strace wait on long time

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(6011),
  sin_addr=inet_addr("x.x.x.x")}, 16) = ? ERESTARTSYS
  (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)'
```

I tried this:

```
# hostname
```

use this for `/etc/hosts`:

```
nameofhost=hostname
```

add this `$nameofhost` to the `/etc/hosts` on line starting with

```
127.0.0.1 localhost ... $nameofhost
```

Cheers!

Comment: This solution also works if the samba connection is (extremly) slow.

Answer (score 55):

[mc/subshell](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/src/subshell/common.c) integration is a frequent culprit; to verify, try:

```
alias mc="mc --nosubshell"
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. I can see that I have access to cmd-o, but I can't type any commands.

Comment: doesnt work for me

Comment: This solution makes MC starts on mac instantaneously. Otherwise it takes 7 seconds.

Comment: a handy shorter option is `mc -u`

Comment: it works for me

Answer (score 15):

Actually editing `/etc/hosts` solved the problem for me.

My `mc` took 10 seconds to start due to the fact that during startup `mc` tries to resolve the local hostname to an IP address.

I added to `/etc/hosts` the following line (my hostname is FOO)

```
127.0.0.2 FOO.domain FOO
```

That instantly solved the problem.

Comment: Why did you use `127.0.0.2` but not `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: any x,y,z in 127.x.y.z will work equally well (the entire IP range is reserved for the local machine)

Answer (score 14):

```
mc -X
```

worked for me (xterm disabled)

Comment: This was the problem for me as well. `DISPLAY` environment variable was set to `localhost:10.0`, but there was no X server listening there on that server with no display.

Comment: For me `mc -u -X` helped (disabling xterm + subshell).

Comment: `mc -X` solved problem for me, but `mc -u -X` is more faster than just `-X`.

Answer (score 6):

Check

```
host $(hostname)
```

get quick result

`mc` use `hostname` at first to connect to internal service

In similar situation on Fedora 18, I add `hostname` value to `/etc/hosts` and it helps.

Comment: mc internal service? may be we could change some configuration to fix mc to not require changing /etc/hosts? or is the /etc/hosts broken and mc expects it to be corrected?

Comment: oh, I just found that this works here: `alias mc='TERM=linux mc'`

Comment: Really /etc/hosts is broken, from some point of view. Impossible to resolve own hostname to own ip. I don't know why mc depend on it there.

Comment: What do you mean by `host 'hostname'`? It returns the same as `host 'aaaa'`, `host 'aaab'` and the endless list of non-existing hosts. Did yoy mean MC is trying to resolve non-existing host?

Comment: Sorry, apostrophe must be there in place of single quotes. Answer fixed.
In some way Yes. MC make connection to own server by Your hostname, so it get nonexistent host and make many tries.

Comment: So `host `hostname`` returned my hostname. What next?

Answer (score 6):

It might start slow because it starts a subshell (shown when you press <kbd>Ctrl + O</kbd>) and displays the UI only when the subshell started. I use zsh and I noticed when I remove my `~/.zshrc` file mc starts instantly.

Comment: See https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3580 for a possible improvement by launching the subshell in background.

Comment: So, there's a need to recompile it?

Answer (score 4):

It took about 10 seconds to start `mc`. Running `strace -r -tt -o mc.strace mc` I got:

```
...
 0.000023 pipe([7, 8])              = 0
 0.000028 clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fcad000fa50) = 3332
 0.000247 write(5, " PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND"..., 75) = 75
 0.000050 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x449960, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fcaced23740}, NULL, 8) = 0
 0.000034 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {10, 0}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 999996})
 0.000039 read(5, " PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND"..., 128) = 76
 0.000032 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 999996}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 985005})
 0.015050 read(5, "[yuri@yuri ~]  PROM", 128) = 19
 0.000031 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 985005}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 985001})
 0.000036 read(5, "PT_COM", 128)    = 6
 0.000026 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 985001}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984998})
 0.000033 read(5, "MAND=", 128)     = 5
 0.000026 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984998}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984995})
 0.000033 read(5, "${PR", 128)      = 4
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984995}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984992})
 0.000034 read(5, "OMPT", 128)      = 4
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984992}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984989})
 0.000034 read(5, "_COM", 128)      = 4
 0.000026 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984989}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984986})
 0.000034 read(5, "MAND", 128)      = 4
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984986}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984983})
 0.000033 read(5, ":+$", 128)       = 3
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984983}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984980})
 0.000033 read(5, "PRO", 128)       = 3
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984980}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984977})
 0.000033 read(5, "MPT", 128)       = 3
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984977}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984974})
 0.000033 read(5, "_CO", 128)       = 3
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984974}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984971})
 0.000033 read(5, "MMA", 128)       = 3
 0.000026 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984971}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984968})
 0.000032 read(5, "ND;", 128)       = 3
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984968}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984965})
 0.000033 read(5, " }", 128)        = 2
 0.000026 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984965}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984962})
 0.000033 read(5, "'pw", 128)       = 3
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984962}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984959})
 0.000033 read(5, "d>", 128)        = 2
 0.000026 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984959}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984956})
 0.000032 read(5, "&8;", 128)       = 3
 0.000026 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984956}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984953})
 0.000032 read(5, "ki", 128)        = 2
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984953}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984950})
 0.000033 read(5, "ll ", 128)       = 3
 0.000026 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984950}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984947})
 0.000032 read(5, "-S", 128)        = 2
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984947}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984944})
 0.000033 read(5, "TO", 128)        = 2
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984944}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984941})
 0.000033 read(5, "P ", 128)        = 2
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984941}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984938})
 0.000033 read(5, "$$", 128)        = 2
 0.000033 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984938}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984935})
 0.000034 read(5, "'\r\n", 128)     = 3
 0.000025 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984935}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984886})
 0.000082 read(5, "bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 1: sy"..., 128) = 128
 0.000033 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984886}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 984882})
 0.000071 read(5, "tory -r; ; pwd>&8;kill -STOP $$'"..., 128) = 48
 0.000061 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 984882}) = 0 (Timeout)
 9.995037 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fcaced23740}, NULL, 8) = 0
 0.000090 write(1, "\33[?1001s\33[?1002h\33[?1006h", 24) = 24
 0.000066 write(1, "\33[?2004h", 8) = 8
 0.000034 geteuid()                 = 1000
 0.000064 access("/home/yuri/.config/mc/filehighlight.ini", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 0.000061 access("/etc/mc/filehighlight.ini", R_OK) = 0
 0.000042 access("/etc/mc/filehighlight.ini", R_OK) = 0
 0.000044 stat("/etc/mc/filehighlight.ini", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1119, ...}) = 0
 0.000035 open("/etc/mc/filehighlight.ini", O_RDONLY) = 9
...
```

Looking at this output, I decided to start `mc` with empty `PROMPT_COMMAND` (`PROMPT_COMMAND= mc`), and it started instantly. I had there supposedly common:

```
history -a; history -c; history -r;
```

**UPD** Upon some more digging, it turns out it has nothing to do with history (`PROMPT_COMMAND=';' strace -r -tt -o mc.strace -s 1000 mc`):

```
 0.000197 write(5, " PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }'pwd>&8;kill -STOP $$'\n", 75) = 75
 0.000068 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x449960, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f12567fc660}, NULL, 8) = 0
 0.000049 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {10, 0}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 999996})
 0.000055 read(5, " PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }'pwd>&8;kill -STOP $$'\r\n", 128) = 76
 0.000050 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 999996}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 981008})
 0.019073 read(5, "bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'\r\nbash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 0: `;'\r\n", 128) = 105
 0.000041 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 981008}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980786})
 0.000292 read(5, "[\33[1;30myuri\33[0m@\33[1;33myuri\33[0m ~]  PROM", 128) = 41
 0.000070 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980786}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980782})
 0.000075 read(5, "PT_COMMAN", 128) = 9
 0.000061 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980782}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980778})
 0.000058 read(5, "D=${PRO", 128)   = 7
 0.000047 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980778}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980775})
 0.000059 read(5, "MPT_CO", 128)    = 6
 0.000048 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980775}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980772})
 0.000058 read(5, "MMAND", 128)     = 5
 0.000047 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980772}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980768})
 0.000056 read(5, ":+$P", 128)      = 4
 0.000047 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980768}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980764})
 0.000057 read(5, "ROMPT", 128)     = 5
 0.000047 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980764}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980761})
 0.000056 read(5, "_COM", 128)      = 4
 0.000047 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980761}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980758})
 0.000057 read(5, "MAND", 128)      = 4
 0.000046 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980758}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980755})
 0.000057 read(5, "; }'", 128)      = 4
 0.000046 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980755}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980752})
 0.000056 read(5, "pwd>", 128)      = 4
 0.000047 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980752}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980749})
 0.000057 read(5, "&8;k", 128)      = 4
 0.000047 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980749}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980746})
 0.000057 read(5, "ill", 128)       = 3
 0.000058 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980746}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980743})
 0.000057 read(5, " -ST", 128)      = 4
 0.000046 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980743}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980740})
 0.000058 read(5, "OP ", 128)       = 3
 0.000046 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980740}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980736})
 0.000056 read(5, "$$'\r\n", 128)   = 5
 0.000048 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980736}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980721})
 0.000069 read(5, "bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'\r\nbash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 1: `;; pwd>&8;kill -STOP $$'\r\n", 128) = 128
 0.000049 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980721}) = 1 (in [5], left {9, 980713})
 0.000062 read(5, "[\33[1;30myuri\33[0m@\33[1;33myuri\33[0m ~] ", 128) = 36
 0.000047 select(8, [5 7], NULL, NULL, {9, 980713}) = 0 (Timeout)
 9.990855 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f12567fc660}, NULL, 8) = 0
```

My conjuncture is that `mc` messes with `PROMPT_COMMAND` in a wrong way. It changes `PROMPT_COMMAND` so that if it contains `;`, that triggers bash error. As such, nothing is written to descriptor `8`, which blocks the process until timeout. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: I know this is an old answer and all. But maybe I am lucky and you mind explaning why you conclude from the strace output that something was wrong with `PROMPT_COMMAND`. I had the same issue and I also solved it by removing `history -a` from my `PROMPT_COMMAND` but I have no idea why that helps and I have no idea where the connection between that and `select(8, [6,7], ...)` (which apparently causes the slow down of MC with the timeout) is. Maybe you can help me understand the solution.

Comment: @degill Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update! You are right, just putting `;` in the `PROMPT_COMMAND` does have the same effect of timing out. I know added `history -a` back to my `PROMPT_COMMAND` (within `~/.local/share/mc/bashrc`) and everything works fine. Still interesting though what is up with the `;`

Comment: The upstream bug entry is at https://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/3534.

Answer (score 3):

Just solved the same problem on FreeBSD. I think, it's more correct to edit `/etc/hosts` in the following way:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.my.domain myhost.my.domain myhost
```

because the `hosts` file entry syntax is (see [hosts(5) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html)):

```
IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]
```

So, if you just add in your `hosts` file something like

```
127.0.0.2 myhost.my.domain myhost
```

then you will get

```
root@myhost:~# ping myhost
PING myhost.my.domain (127.0.0.2): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Can't assign requested address
ping: sendto: Can't assign requested address
ping: sendto: Can't assign requested address
ping: sendto: Can't assign requested address
^C
--- myhost.my.domain ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

But if you edit your `hosts` file like in the first example, you will get the correct ping answer:

```
root@myhost:~# ping myhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.030/0.044/0.060/0.010 ms
```

MC starts fast both ways.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue for a very long time and I ended up not using Midnight Commander anymore...

But I recently found the solution!!! In my case, it was only related to my alternative shell: I'm using fish. http://fishshell.com/

The two together doesn't work great. I just changed my script to make sure mc use bash and not fish.

Comment: And why would fish cause such problems?

Answer (score 1):

> DISPLAY=;mc

works for me.
Using **MobaXterm** X11-Forwarding, automatic DISPLAY redirection.

Comment: This may happen when the X-server is not up (specified by DISPLAY).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MobaXterm to connect to SSH on your server you may need to turn off X11 forwarding to start mc shortly. This is what slows down the mc start.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have exactly the same problem.
Usually it was due to missing hostname line in /etc/hosts,
but this time the reason turned out quite different - the file **".bashrc"** , to be specific these lines:

```
# The next line updates PATH for Yandex Cloud CLI.
if [ -f '/home/vasya/yandex-cloud/path.bash.inc' ]; then source '/home/vasya/yandex-cloud/path.bash.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for yc.
if [ -f '/home/vasya/yandex-cloud/completion.bash.inc' ]; then source '/home/vasya/yandex-cloud/completion.bash.inc'; fi

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

When i remove them  the launch time of mc diminished from two seconds to just instant.

So the proposition - if none of the above solutions help - try to investigate **".bashrc"**

Answer (score -1):

In my case, 10 seconds of slow down was because of

```
[oh-my-zsh] Would you like to update? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to delete line "search whatever.something" from `/etc/resolv.conf`

`/etc/hosts` should have the lines:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

127.0.0.2 hostname.domain hostname
```

"hostname" is your hostname and "domain" is your domain.

Comment: That makes some sense _only_ if the machine is never connected to the 'net. That file is filled in by DHCP (or when the Internet connection is configured).