# Midnight Commander on server slow startup due to attempting to access my local IP

Tags: mc

My case is similar to some of the proposed solution in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57439/slow-start-of-midnight-commander) where on startup mc attempt to resolve & connect to hostname. Except, instead of accessing the hostname, the mc running on server instead attempt to access my *local* IP.

If I SSH directly to my server, the last line from `strace mc` will be :

> connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(6000), sin_addr=inet_addr("139.X.X.X")}, 16

before it seem to hung up for a while and then load mc. 139.X.X.X is my local client IP. My server's IP is 5.x.x.x

If I reroute the SSH through my server itself, either using secondary SSH connection for socks proxy or connecting to OpenVPN running on the server, mc load up instantly.

Is there a way to just disable any attempt to connect at startup, or is there a way to trace where does my server decide to pass my client's IP to mc?